# Como ativar evento clicando em qualquer lugar da tela?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos

Eu tenho uma validação de CPF e esse "evento" é ativado quando eu clico no botão "validar".

Eu queria que esse "evento" fosse ativado quando o usuario clicar fora do input, tipo ele digitou o CPF e clicou e qualquer lugar da tela, ai esse "evento" de validação é ativado sem precisar de botões. o meu codigo esta assim:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Validar CPF com Máscara by TchekiGamer</title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="language" content="PT-BR"/>

  <script src="http://www.geradorcpf.com/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.geradorcpf.com/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.geradorcpf.com/jquery.maskedinput-1.1.4.pack.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");   

    $("#botaoValidarCPF").click(function() {       
      if($("#cpf").val() == '') {           
        $("#saida").html("Informe um CPF");         
        return false;   
      }    
      if(validarCPF($("#cpf").val())) {         
        $("#saida").html("<span style='color: green'>CPF Válido!</span>");     
      } 
      else {            
        $("#saida").html("<span style='color: red'>CPF Inválido!</span>");     }    });});
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>

      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

        <div align="center" id="saida1">
          <label>Digite o seu cpf</label>
          <input name="cpf" type="text" id="cpf"/> <!-- class="saida"-->
        </div>

        <div align="center">
          <input style="font-size: 15px; cursor: pointer" type="button" name="botaoValidarCPF" id="botaoValidarCPF" value="Validar CPF"/>
        </div>

        <div align="center" id="saida" class="style7"> <!-- aparece mensagem de CPF Invalido --></div>

      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento onblur da input, seu código ficaria assim :

```
    $("#cpf").blur(function (){
    if($("#cpf").val() == '') {           
        $("#saida").html("Informe um CPF");         
        return false;   
    }    
    if(validarCPF($("#cpf").val())) {         
        $("#saida").html("<span style='color: green'>CPF Válido!</span>");     
    } 
    else {            
        $("#saida").html("<span style='color: red'>CPF Inválido!</span>");     
    } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solução 1

Você pode usar o método hasFocus(), o qual vai conferir se o input tem foco e, se não tiver, você faz a validação.

Uso simples do método:

```
if (!objeto.hasFocus()) {
    //validação
}
```

## Solução 2

Você pode validar enquanto o usuário digita, usando um evento oninput.

Uso simples:

```
objeto.addEventListener("input", validarCPF);
```